# Javascript posting values into multiple labels created in a for loop

Tags: javascript

Here is my code currently below;

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var number1 = document.getElementById("text").value;
    var number2 = document.getElementById("selector").value;
    var result = number1 / number2;
    var len = number2;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        var labelOutput = document.createElement("label");
        labelOutput.setAttribute("id", "label"+i);
        labelOutput.setAttribute("value", result);

        //Inserts after div tag
        //document.getElementById("results").insertAfter();
    }
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to get it so once it has worked out the result it will create labels based on the length / amount that has been divided by for example if 100 / 2 = 50 it will create two labels which have the same value (this case being 50) but with different id's label1 and label2

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: It won't generate the labels once the function is clicked via button / run, I'm not sure if I need to appendChild the label afterwards or whether I'm missing something

Comment: *"Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question."*

Comment: It looks like you're creating the labels, but, yeah, you're not adding them to the document anywhere so...you won't see them in the document. I still don't understand the question, but if you're just trying to add the labels to the document, then do so: `document.body.appendChild(labelOutput);`

Comment: What are you expecting to see? You haven't created anything that would display anything, so if you're hoping to visually see something in your page, you won't. A label, without content, doesn't display anything. Do `labelOutput.textContent = 'foo';` and you might start to see something.

Comment: I suspect you may not be familiar with what a `label` is/does. For example, setting `value` on a `label` isn't really a thing one would normally do. I suggest maybe reading up on labels a bit and how to use them

Comment: @Aaronius if you look below I changed it to innerHTML and I do know what a label does thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your original question wasn't very clear, you hit the nail on the head in your comment (emphasis is mine):

> It won't generate the labels once the function is clicked via button / run, I'm not sure if **I need to appendChild the label afterwards** or whether I'm missing something

JavaScript doesn't automatically append elements to the page when you create them, therefore you must do that yourself.

**Edit**: As StackOverflow user [Aaronius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459966/aaronius) mentioned in a comment on your question, you can use [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) function for this.

Comment: I'll try rephrasing it, the code is supposed to run so once a value is typed in and selected by divide amount it will create a result stored in the result variable. with the result variable it will give a length for the for loop which would loop x amount of times to get x amount of labels with a value. so label 1 and 2 would have 50 for example because I've done 100 / 2 = 50 with 2 being loop length. Hopefully that makes more sense :S

Comment: That doesn't make much more sense, sorry. Perhaps you should try editing your question and use some of the tips you learned from the [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var number1 = document.getElementById("text").value;
    var number2 = document.getElementById("selector").value;
    var result = number1 / number2;
    var len = number2;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        var labelOutput = document.createElement("label");
        labelOutput.innerHTML = result;
        labelOutput.setAttribute("name", i + ".");
        labelOutput.setAttribute("id","lbl_"+i +"\n");

        document.body.appendChild(labelOutput);
    }
}
</script>
```

This is what I was after, thanks all who answered.